# Showing 'str' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: django

I am trying to build a quiz app, where a user can select an option and the option is saved against its question in a particular quiz.

So i tried using the below approach. I created my models.py as below.

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    topic=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    number_of_questions=models.IntegerField()
    difficulty=models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=difficulty_choices)
    TimeLimit=models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    def get_questions(self):
        return self.questions_set.all()[:self.number_of_questions]


class Questions(models.Model):
    text=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    quiz=models.ForeignKey(Quiz,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    correct=models.CharField(max_length=25)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.text)
    def get_answers(self):
        return self.answers_set.all()
class Answers(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Questions, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Question: {self.question.text}, Answer: {self.text}"
class UserAnswer(models.Model):
    quiz=models.ForeignKey(Quiz,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Questions, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answers, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
```

now the question and eahc of its respective answers is displayed in a form. the options are in the forms of radio select button. I have created that form below.

```
class QuizForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Quiz
        fields = ['text']
        exclude = ["text"]  # Add other fields as needed
        
    selected_answer = forms.ChoiceField(
        label="Select the correct answer",
        choices=[],  # We'll update choices dynamically
        widget=forms.RadioSelect
    )
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QuizForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        quiz_instance = kwargs.get('instance')
        questions = quiz_instance.get_questions()
        for question in questions:
            answers = question.get_answers()
            answer_choices = [(answer.id, answer.text) for answer in answers]
            
            # Update the choices of the selected_answer field
            self.fields['selected_answer'].choices = answer_choices
```

Now in order to render this form and save the answer selected i created the below views.py

```
@login_required
def quizquestions(request, pk):
    try:
        quiz_instance = Quiz.objects.get(pk=pk)
        
    except Quiz.DoesNotExist:
        # Handle the case when the question doesn't exist
        return redirect('quiz_not_found')  # Redirect to an appropriate view
     
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QuizForm(request.POST, instance=quiz_instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            
            
            selected_answer=request.POST.get("selected_answer")
            question_answered=selected_answer.question
            selected_answer=Answers.objects.get(text=selected_answer.text,question=question_answered)        
            user_answer=form.save(commit=False)
            # Create a UserAnswer instance to track the selected answer
            user_answer,created = UserAnswer.objects.get_or_create(
            user=request.user,
            question=question_answered
            )
            
            user_answer.quiz=quiz_instance
            user_answer.answer = selected_answer
            user_answer.save()
            # Save the form after creating the UserAnswer instance
            
            
            # Redirect to the next question or a thank you page
            #return redirect('next_question_view')
    else:
        form = QuizForm(instance=quiz_instance)
    context={'form':form,'quiz':quiz_instance}
    
    return render(request, 'users/quiz.html', context)
```

However I got the error 'str' object has no attribute 'text'. So what I think is in the line
`selected_answer=request.POST.get("selected_answer")`, it is getting the answer.text.But if you look back into my forms.py `answer_choices = [(answer.id, answer.text) for answer in answers]`, shouldn't it get the answer.id?